# dwm: uneven window tiling

Tags: linux, window-manager, dwm

So I started using dwm recently and ran into an issue.

When I'm in tiled mode(mod+t) with 1 master and 2 slaves, bottom of master window doesn't align with the bottom of the slave window.

[image]

Master(left), Slave(right)

Above picture shows the problem without using any patches. It's very noticeable when used with gaps.

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after some researching I found out that **this has nothing to do with dwm but the terminal.**
I was using st terminal. I tried alacritty and it worked just fine.
So to fix this in st, I had to apply **anysize** patch,

https://st.suckless.org/patches/anysize/

Comment: You can also just disable resize hints in dwm's `config.h`.

Comment: resize hints is the correct answer :)